# .send not working vba but .display is

Tags: vba, excel, sendmail

My ".send" is not working however my ".display" is? I keep getting an object defined error. and when I debug it highlights the ".send". Any suggestions?

```
Sub SendEmails()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

For i = 8 To 10
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olMail
    .BCC = Cells(i, 1).Value
    .Subject = Cells(i, 2).Value
    .Body = "Hello " & Cells(i, 3).Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 4).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 6).Value
    .Attachments.Add "H:\Shared\Public\Focus 6\Private Equity\Send Emails\2017-01-18\EY - Capitalizing on Opportunities (PE O&G).pdf"
    .Send

    End With
Next

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: you may have a warning regarding access to outlook, in outlook. https://community.sophos.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-03-00-00-00-00-69-59/outlook.png

Answer (score 1):

As @Nathan_Sav mentioned, you can probably play around with your Outlook security features. As an alternative, you can experiment with the `.SendKeys` function...though please note that this is not a very reliable method, especially if you are going to need other people/other machines to try and use this macro.

But if you replace

```
.Send
```

With

```
.SendKeys "%S"
```

It might work for you.

Comment: SendKeys "%S" doesn't work when the system is locked. The workaround is to save the email to an email folder. On the add_item event of the folder write code to send it. So when an item gets added to that folder, the item will be sent automatically

Answer (score 0):

`.Display` will give you a view of the email. If this step works, then `.Send` will work efficiently. When using `.Send` you will receive a message box acknowledging that a 3rd party program is trying to access outlook (If everything is configured correctly). To fix this if it is not configured, open the workbook and then open the VBE (Alt+F11). From there goto Tools-->References and uncheck any that are marked "Missing". If possible, look for the appropriate Outlook Object library and check it.

```
Sub SendEmails()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

For i = 8 To 10
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olMail
    .BCC = Cells(i, 1).Value
    .Subject = Cells(i, 2).Value
    .Body = "Hello " & Cells(i, 3).Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 4).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 6).Value
    .Attachments.Add "H:\Shared\Public\Focus 6\Private Equity\Send Emails\2017-01-18\EY - Capitalizing on Opportunities (PE O&G).pdf"
    .Display

    End With
Next

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but your suggestion still doesn't seem to work. I get the following error message:  Run-time error '287: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Thanks for this - gave me the clue I needed in order to discover that the emails were going into my junk folder. *(Who'd a thunk that emails* ***from*** *me* ***to*** *me would be delivered into the junk folder - arghhhh.)*

Answer (score 0):

Most organizational emails have a  mandatory document/email labelling policy where you have to choose between options like public, restricted, confidential, etc. If your outlook is setup so that you must choose one of these options before sending the email, this might be the reason for getting an error. There aren't many solutions that I know of for this issue, other than deactivating the plugin that requires you to label emails before sending them. But maybe someone else may have other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was too facing this issue, .display goes well but stuck with .send.

Then I realized that the address in TO or CC or BCC should be separated by semicolon + space (; ) and not comma (,). Try this one and check, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying first then sending. I was having this issue intermittently when I realized that just going to .send works if you have one or more emails entered properly as full addresses. However, if you just enter the contact names, or you are using email groups, it throws an error. But if you display first, the contact names and email groups get converted to a usable format and then you can send it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).